# what are needed to make my own SNMP Agent and server?

Tags: sockets, snmp, winsnmp

Hii,
I want to make my own snmp server and agent.with my own MIB and OID's.
how can i do it??and where to start??

And if i want to use windows SNMP service and extend it and insert my own OID's into its MIB
then ,is it possible??.n if yes,how can i do this??

Comment: From bitter experience, SNMP is a pretty lousy protocol for what it does (it does have an excuse, it was written for machines of extremely limited capabilities). If you have affirmative reason for using it, have fun.

Comment: Thanx msx,..can u suggest me some other protocol which will provide me all the features which SNMP provides us??

Comment: SNMP is still a feasible protocol. It was designed for simple applications, so if you don't plan a complex product, why not use it? Even companies such as Cisco, HP use SNMP still. Its replacement TR-069 is not yet popular.

Comment: If you plan to extend Windows SNMP service, you can start from here, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750391.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an excellent open-source implementation for the .NET framework called [SharpSnmpLib](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpsnmplib).  It can implement a normal SNMP server, and it allows you to load your own custom MIBS.

A couple of tips:

- You can find existing MIB's at [oidview](http://www.oidview.com/) or the [Cisco Mib Browser](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/public.jsp)
- Avoid v3 and the RFC's that belong to it (in fact, I'd avoid the RFC's at all, they're confusing and cover many areas that were not adopted)
- Test early and often with machines as close to the production setup as you can

Comment: Can i make my own MIB and provide my own OID's and their values??..Can i use this library for commercial purpose??.

Comment: The library is LGPLed, so you can use in commercial projects. The samples, such as the agent/server reference design is covered by MIT license.

Comment: i have found a library SnmpSharpNet   http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/
Can i use it commercially??.it is licensed under LGPL.

Comment: One more think Is it possible to implement everything ie. create my own MIB ,OID's etc with this library??..
thanx

Answer (score 2):

If you *ever* start implementing **any** *standardized* protocol, the first step is to read the standards defining it. In case of SNMPv3. the relevant standards are

RFC:s

- [3411](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3411),
- [3412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3412),
- [3414](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3413),
- [3414](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414),
- [3515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3415),
- [3416](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416),
- [3417](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3417) and
- [3418](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3418)

The good (and bad) thing about RFC's is that they usually very clearly state what you **MUST**, **SHOULD**, **MUST NOT**, **SHOULD NOT** and **MAY** do in your implemention.